# Is there a zsh command for enabling the developer mode on Safari?

Tags: macos, shell, command-line, safari

I have been wondering if there is a shorthand method or command that can enable the developer tools of Safari.
So far I only know how to do it manually by changing it in preference setting. [Sorry too new to post images just yet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wf4LQ.png)

Comment: You used to be able to enable the Debug menu by quitting Safari, running `defaults write com.apple.Safari IncludeInternalDebugMenu 1`, and then starting Safari.  You can disable it again by quitting, running `defaults write com.apple.Safari IncludeInternalDebugMenu 0` and restarting Safari. I'm not sure if this still works in Big Sur.

Comment: @JoeBlock I've tried this on several MacOS with sudo privilege but it doesn't seem to work ?

Comment: If it doesn't work in a regular terminal session, this is one of the cases where `sudo` will probably not help. `sudo` runs a command as root. Because it's running as root and not as your user account, any changes it makes with `defaults write` will be in _root_'s user settings and not yours.